# mysql write and read geographical bounds (rectangle)

Tags: mysql, gis

I need to store map bounds in a MySQL database. I've spent some time on the docs for geospacial extensions, but it's difficult and in my case unnecessary to learn all related info (WKT, WKB etc.)
I just need a way to store a rectangle of coordinates and read it back later.
Of course I could also just write the raw coordinates to floats, but if it isn't to complicated, I would prefer to have it in 1 column.

So, what's the simplest possible SQL code for that requirement?

PS: I already use a POINT value in that table, so the extensions are installed and working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store polygons in a geometry column within mysql. This will then let you perform some geometry function on them (if you need to - but doesn't sound like you do)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/polygon-property-functions.html

```
SET @poly = 'Polygon((0 0,0 3,3 0,0 0))';
SELECT Area(GeomFromText(@poly));
```

Edit:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (`geo` geometry NOT NULL) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
INSERT INTO test SET geo = GeomFromText('Polygon((0 0,0 3,3 0,0 0))');
SELECT asText(geo) FROM `test`;
```

Try the above sql statements. I create a table with a geometry column, Add the polygon then select the data astext.

Comment: What does the @ ? I already tried this without @ and the field was still null afterwards.

Comment: The @ signifies that it's a user-defined variable. SET is what you use to define the variable and then that variable is being used in the SELECT statement.

Comment: Hmm, that's what I already did. However, when setting the value with update statement, it's always null, although no error is reported. Inserting works. But that's not what I need.

Comment: I found out. Missed the double brackets. It's hard to debug if no error message is generated...

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called **[serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization)** /you can visit link and read about Programming language support/. For example in php exists function called serialize ( [php serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) ) which is very helpful in your case. You can use it then store the value and later use [php unserialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) to read it in php.

I know MyISAM supports some spatial extensions but in my opinion using them is not as flexible as serialization.

Cheers!
I hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're ONLY interested in storing and retrieving the points of a column, then I'd suggest just dumping the points (comma separated, or however you like) into a BLOB field. If you ever want to use any spatial analysis functions, you may want to look into the [Polygon class](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gis-class-polygon.html) and use your points to define a polygon for each rectangle of coordinates.